# Google maps World bounds still gives world repeat

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bounds

So i'm currently working on a map and i want to make it so that users cant pan outside the map (so no repeating world), so when they zoom all the way out they see the whole map like this:
[image]

and when they try to pan left or right they cant when zoomed all the way out

i currently have it so that the user still can pan left and right but it still has a bit of repaid on it example snippet bellow

does someone know how to achieve this or is what i'm trying to do no possible

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dev = true;
  var zoomed = false;

  //Google Maps JS
  //Map styling
  var Mapstyle = [{
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "simplified"
    }]
  }, {
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#19191a"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "water",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#1a1a1a"
    }, {
      "lightness": 8
    }]
  }, {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "on"
    }, {
      "lightness": 25
    }]
  }];

  //Set Map
  function init() {

    //Calculate Center of the world when map loads
    var w = window.innerWidth;

    var mapOptions = {
      minZoom: getZoom(w),
      zoom: getZoom(w),
      center: getLatLng(w),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      styles: Mapstyle
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);


    //Get visitors location and place maker on top of it
    $.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
      getCountry(location.country_code);
    });

    function getCountry(country) {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': country
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }

    //Testing bounds
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
      allowedBounds = map.getBounds();
      if (dev === true) {
        console.log(allowedBounds);
      }
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
        checkBounds(allowedBounds);
      });
    });

    // Limit map area
    function checkBounds(allowedBounds) {

      if (!allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
        var C = map.getCenter();
        var X = C.lng();
        var Y = C.lat();

        var AmaxX = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
        var AmaxY = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
        var AminX = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
        var AminY = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

        if (X < AminX) {
          X = AminX;
        }
        if (X > AmaxX) {
          X = AmaxX;
        }
        if (Y < AminY) {
          Y = AminY;
        }
        if (Y > AmaxY) {
          Y = AmaxY;
        }

        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Y, X));
      }
    }

    //Resize Function
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
      if (zoomed === false) {
        map.setZoom(getZoom(4));
        zoomed = false;
      } else {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
      }
    });
  }

  function getZoom(w) {
    if (w <= 512) {
      if (dev === true) {
        console.log("Zoom level 1");
      }
      return 1;
    } else if (w > 512 && w <= 1024) {
      if (dev === true) {
        console.log("Zoom level 2")
      }
      return 2;
    } else if (w > 1024 && w <= 2048) {
      if (dev === true) {
        console.log("Zoom level 3")
      }
      return 3;
    } else if (w > 2048 && w <= 4096) {
      if (dev === true) {
        console.log("Zoom level 4")
      }
      return 4;
    } else if (w > 4096 && w <= 8192) {
      if (dev === true) {
        console.log("Zoom level 5")
      }
      return 3;
    }
  }

  function getLatLng(w) {
    if ((w <= 512) || (w > 512 && w <= 1024)) {
      var smallLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
      return smallLatLng;
    } else {
      var normalLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(25, 0);
      return normalLatLng;
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #19191A !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id=map></div>
```

ok after some tweaking i have made it a bit more dynamic but i still have the issue that i can pan to the left.

the code i'm using now:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
        allowedBounds = map.getBounds();
        if(dev === true ) { console.log(allowedBounds); }
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function () {
            checkBounds(allowedBounds);
        });
    });

    // Limit map area
    function checkBounds(allowedBounds) {

        if (!allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
            var C = map.getCenter();
            var X = C.lng();
            var Y = C.lat();

            var AmaxX = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
            var AmaxY = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
            var AminX = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
            var AminY = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

            if (X < AminX) { X = AminX; }
            if (X > AmaxX) { X = AmaxX; }
            if (Y < AminY) { Y = AminY; }
            if (Y > AmaxY) { Y = AmaxY; }

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Y, X));
        }
    }
```

still gives this 
[image]

When draging to the left or right